# XMLHttpRequest cannot load html file

Tags: jquery

when i click on the accolades link this is the error i get

```
OPTIONS file:///D:/Heena/BalajiKumar.com/accolades.html No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 
header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. 

jquery-1.4.2.min.js:130

c.extend.ajax      jquery-1.4.2.min.js:130

c.fn.extend.load      jquery-1.4.2.min.js:120

(anonymous function)      index.html:68

c.event.handle      jquery-1.4.2.min.js:55

j.handle.o      jquery-1.4.2.min.js:49


XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///D:/Heena/BalajiKumar.com/accolades.html. No 'Access-
Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is 
therefore not allowed access.
```

any solutuion. I'm running this on my local machine.

It works perfect on the web server.
But i need to run this locally

Answer (score 0):

Run a local development webserver. Wamp or XAMPP would be a simple choice on windows.

You are getting that error because the file:// protocol is a different 'origin' as far as AJAX is concerned. as long as both the AJAX call and remote file are both hosted on localhost, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to load a file locally via `file://` protocol. jQuery needs `http://` protocol. So, you need a web server like apache or nginx which will serve your files.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is on the request address. If you want to run this locally you can install a local web server like WAMP... This will work.